# UEFI: Install Ubuntu first then Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi, windows-10

What should I do in order to install Windows 10 after I already installed Ubuntu (>= 18.10)? both should work in UEFI mode

GParted shows this after failed Windows installation attempt (/dev/nvme0n1p 4-7 were created at install moment):

[image]

At installation moment I get:

> Windows detected that the EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS.
>   Format the EFI system partition as FAT32, and restart the installation

[image]

Comment: Try labeling the first EFI partition just like the created one, and delete the created one, maybe copy any contents to the frst too.  This is really a Windows question, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you do a fast format of NTFS? If you did, maybe try a full format (writing to every bit).

Comment: This is a windows problem not Ubuntu ;-)

Comment: @ubfan1 - that depends on the point of view; for me Ubuntu is the main actor here, Windows is just expendable annoyance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this way:

1. removed efi & boot flags from the already existing Ubuntu-EFI partition
   (/dev/nvme0n1p5 for me) and let just fat32 flag
2. I removed Windows related partitions (created at installation moment) so that the initially empty space at the end of the disk was restored
3. I restarted the Windows 10 installation -> successful this time

This works because my motherboard (Asus H370-I) allows me to choose the booting partition:

- the previous Ubuntu-EFI one (now just fat32) -> my curent choice
- or the new Windows-EFI one

Then by default I boot Ubuntu but I can switch to Windows from the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same challenge trying to install Windows on my Ubuntu machine.

I used my Mac to format and create the bootable USB Stick, and the issue was how I formated the stick.

At first I had the "GUID Partition Map" scheme set, and I got the above error. But when I changed to "Master Boot Record" the installer worked just fine.

Hope this helps someone else in the same pickle as I was in!